# Firebase Database getDocument is not able to find document title containing apostrophes ( Ex: "we've" )

Tags: ios, swift, database, firebase

## The Problem

I have a firebase firestore database, that acts as a dictionary. Each document is titled after a word. Everything works fine, except for when I am trying to retrieve documents for words containing apostrophes, for example: we've, you're, he's. When I try to run a query for these words in my program, the result will be empty. If I go to my firebase console and run this query, It will bring up word. I am confused at why it is not working in the program.

## My Code

```
func getMyDocument(documentName: String) {

            let docRef = db.collection(K.FBConstants.dictionaryCollectionName).document(documentName)
 
            docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
                
                let result = Result {
                    try document.flatMap {
                        try $0.data(as: WordModel.self)
                    }
                }
                switch result {
                case .success(let wordModel):
                    if let wordModel = wordModel {
                        results.append(wordModel)
                    } else {
                        results.append(nil)
                        print("Document does not exist")
                    }
                case .failure(let error):
                    results.append(nil)
                    print("Error decoding: \(error)")
                }
            }
}
```

In this code, the variable `word` contains the string that would be the document name say "we've". `WordModel` is a custom structure that holds the dictionary information.

## Calling the function

```
getMyDocument(documentName: "we've")
```

Here is a snapshot of the document. The document title is the same as its id.

[image]

Any advice is appreciated. Thank you !

Comment: Please edit the question to show the exact value for `word`.  I suggest hard coding it into your query instead of using a variable, so everyone can see exactly what it is.  Also include a screenshot of the document you expect it to match.  Firestore is telling you that there is no document that matches `word`, but we need a way to see that for ourselves.

Comment: The question states *Firebase Database Query* but there is no query in the code. You're just attempting to read a document by a documentId.

Comment: sorry about that. I just made the edits you both pointed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell given your screenshot, but it might be the case that your query is using a standard single quote (ascii 39), but your document is using a different character, perhaps a curly quote.  I suggest reading [this guide](https://practicaltypography.com/straight-and-curly-quotes.html) for more details.  If your query does not use the same character as whatever is in the document, the query won't work - the strings must be exactly the same.

Comment: Each app might have a different opinion about what to insert when a key is pressed.  This is common.  This is why programmer's editors always take things literally, while word processes do something more appropriate for typesetting.

Comment: Thank you. You are totally correct. apparently when I type the single quote in from my computer in the app simulator, It reads it as ascii 146 but in the database it is ascii 39.

Comment: I see, makes sense. Thanks Doug, I appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your documentId's are being stored with quotes around them. So the string is actually "we've" not the string we've.

See the difference in this screenshot between the two strings of how a documentId of "we've" looks different than a documentId of we've

[image]